# Raster to Polygon is converting the entire image as one polyon

Tags: raster, kml, png

I am attempting to use the raster to polygon tool with a RF Propagation overlay that is in .png format. The png is tied to a KML for the georeferencing from its output software. If i leave the png tied to the KML I am not able to select it as a raster for the raster to polygon. I was able to convert it to a layer and convert it...but it didn't differentiate between the visible pixels in the png and the transparent pixels. I feel like I'm missing something here. Im happy to share the KML if anyone has any ideas.

[image: Pre Conversion]

[image: Post Conversion]

Comment: Kindly mention the software you are using

Comment: Please check that the PNG is paletted and not full colour. You will find that 24/32 bit RGB/RGBA rasters cannot be selected by raster to polygon in *any* GIS software, there's just too many potential values, if this is the case you will need to classify the raster before polygonizing. There isn't enough information in your description, please include the sofware/API you're using and detailed information on the structure of the PNG.